# Saving tiled + scaled rasters from WCS? is it possible?

Tags: qgis, export, wcs

Qgis + grass does a good job at acquiring the layer and displaying the image, In my case a 20m DTM.

I'm wondering if there is a way to automatically export all the tiles in a 1:1 scale off the original WCS that is being used to rasterize the view layer.

I don't mind scripting my own thing.
The end goal is to extract tiles of a predetermined amount of pixels in a 1:1 geographical scale (so *20 the maximum res of my DTM).

Any pointers or ideas on where to start with the python scripting on this would be most welcome, if a preexisting solution is not already available.

Comment: What is "WGS" in this context?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: You can use gdal2tiles command line utility of gdal, there is a QGIS processing algorithm interface to it in GDAL/Raster miscellaneuos/gdal2tiles.

Comment: WCS * thanks for making me notice I wrote the wrong thing.

I tried the Gdal2Tiles command, Need to play further with it, but I do not see any way to resize or rather export a specific scale...